# Using Value in Whole App and Manupulate That Value

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I want to ask question about my app let me explain to you.My app like this one. Ok

I'm giving a example. At the first we have a super value which is 350 ( this value should use only one time )

When i wrote 100 into text field and clicked done

Remain Score is 350 - 100  = 250

While not closing my app i wrote that text field again but diffirent number like 85 and clicked done

Remain Score is 250 - 85  = 165

and the third of course not closing app , i again wrote text field another number like 50 and clicked done

Remain Score is 165 - 50  = 115

this continue like this which i want to create.

in my app

İn my app it going to like this...

When i wrote 100 into text field and clicked done

Remain Score is 350 - 100  = 250

While not closing my app i wrote that text field again but different number like 85 and clicked done

Remain Score is 350 - 85  = 265

and the third of course not closing app , i again wrote text field another number like 50 and clicked done

Remain Score is 350 - 50  = 50

this continue like this. which i already wrote this code.

Bascily

```
    int playerscore = [_txt_score.text intValue];
    int gamescore = 501;
    int currentscore = gamescore - playerscore;
```

when i clicked done button second time the processes start over i just want to manipulate gamescore value, But i could not do it.

Comment: It depends how and where is your gamescore stored. Which object has it?

Comment: gamescore stored in app, i didn't use any database related with it.  Actually i need a guidance. Maybe it's too simple but i couldn't solve it.

Comment: It really depends on the architecture of your app. But one solution could be to set it on the AppDelegate.

Comment: Could give me sample code how to use with App Delegate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) create variable value in appDelegate.h file @propertise and @synthesise it

2) set its value like below:
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication  sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.value  -=   5;

Comment: describe your questing briefly.